# username may only contain alphanumeric characters or single hyphens, and cannot begin or end with a hyphen

Tags: regex

my app requires a regex that validates the GitHub username convention (see title), i have tried:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

but it only matches strings longer than 1 character.

in the meanwhile, i have a javascript code that does the same function, but i'd like to refactor it using regex for performance reasons

EDIT: this validates it `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$` - make  `[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]` part optional